# Geth always returning a 0 balance?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, wallets, synchronization, balances

i´m mining now for about 3 days with 3 rigs each with over 50Mh/s, but my balance is still 0. Does anybody know why ?

[image]

Comment: What command did you use to start your miner?

Comment: timeout /t 15 setx GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR 0 setx GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE 100 setx GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS 1 setx GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 100 setx GPU_SINGLE_ALLOC_PERCENT 100 ethdcrminer64.exe -epool us1.ethermine.org:4444 -ewal 0xe26edb0ba08ea96e2624a58bbe1ad2b2008115f3.Miner102 -epsw x -mode 1 -tt 68 -allpools 1 pause